# Overload resolution: assignment of empty braces

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution

I wrote some code `S s;` ... `s = {};`, expecting it to end up the same as `S s = {};`. However it didn't. The following example reproduces the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    S(): a(5) { }
    S(int t): a(t) {}

    S &operator=(int t)  { a = t; return *this; }
    S &operator=(S const &t) = default;

    int a;
};

int main()
{
    S s = {};

    S t;
    t = {};

    std::cout << s.a << '\n';
    std::cout << t.a << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
5
0
```

My questions are:

1. Why is `operator=(int)` selected here, instead of "ambiguous" or the other one?
2. Is there a tidy workaround, without changing `S`?

My intent is `s = S{};` . Writing `s = {};` would be convenient if it worked. I'm currently using `s = decltype(s){};` however I'd prefer to avoid repeating the type or the variable name.

Comment: `{}` to `int` is the identity conversion ([\[over.ics.list\]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#9)). `{}` to `S` is a user-defined conversion ([\[over.ics.list\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#6)). I swear I saw a very similar question yesterday...

Comment: @T.C. if so, I guess I could have saved myself some development time by reading more questions yesterday!

Comment: I seem to have made the same mistake many places in my code... e.g. I typically use `void clear() { *this = {}; }` with the intent of restoring an object to its value-initialized state

Comment: Incidentally, `optional` does something fun to make `= {}` work in all cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is `operator=(int)` selected here, instead of "ambiguous" or the other one?

`{}` to `int` is the identity conversion ([[over.ics.list]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#9)). `{}` to `S` is a user-defined conversion ([[over.ics.list]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#6)) (technically, it's `{}` to `const S&`, and goes through [over.ics.list]/8 and [over.ics.ref] first before coming back to [over.ics.list]/6).

The first wins.

> Is there a tidy workaround?

A variation of the trick `std::experimental::optional` pulls to make `t = {}` always make `t` empty.
The key is to make `operator=(int)` a template. If you want to accept `int` and  only `int`, then it becomes

```
template<class Int, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Int, int>{}, int> = 0>
S& operator=(Int t) { a = t; return *this; }
```

Different constraints can be used if you want to enable conversions (you'd probably also want to take the argument by reference in that case).

The point is that by making the right operand's type a template parameter, you block `t = {}` from using this overload - because `{}` is a non-deduced context.

> ...without changing `S`?

Does `template<class T> T default_constructed_instance_of(const T&) { return {}; }` and then `s = default_constructed_instance_of(s);`count?

Comment: Heh, regarding the last line I've now gone with `template<typename T> void reset(T &t) { t = T{}; }`

Answer (score -4):

First of all, the case has nothing to do with the "int" version of the assignment operator, you can just delete it. You can actually delete the other assignment operator too as it will be generated by the compiler. IE this kind of type automatically receives copy/move constructors and the assignment operator. (ie they are not prohibited and you are just repeating what the compiler does automatically with explicit notation)

**The first case**

uses *copy initialization*:

```
S s = {};     // the default constructor is invoked
```

That is a post-construction copy assignment, yet compilers optimize such simple cases. You should use *direction initialization* instead:

```
S s{};        // the default constructor is invoked (as you have it)
```

Note, you can also write:

```
S s;          // the default constructor is invoked if you have it
```

**The second case**

What you should write is *direct initialization* of the right hand side of the copy assignment:

```
t = S{};
```

This notation will invoke the default constructor (if there is one), or value initialization for the members (as long as the type is an aggregate). Here is the relevant info: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: i still dont get what his second case is doing (as written)

Comment: if I remove the "int" version of assignment operator, then the output is `5 5`