# Zero-reinitializing a struct in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, language-lawyer

A POD `struct` can be zero-initialized in C++11 as follows:

```
SomeStruct s{};
```

However, what do I do if I already have an instance of the struct and I want to re-initialize it to zeros? The following seems to work:

```
s = {};
```

Can someone point out the relevant standardese? I assume this is what is happening:

1. A new zero-initialized instance gets created.
2. The new instance is assigned to the existing instance, invoking the implicit assignment operator.

Comment: I don't know about the standard, but - some of this may be optimized away. In fact, if you don't use the 0's, maybe _all_ of this is optimized away.

Comment: There's an explicit rule in there that allows braces on the right hand of an assignment. Your assumption is pretty much correct.

Comment: There is no such thing as "re-initializing". You initialize something once. Just once. What you're doing is assignment and is very different in subtle and not-so-subtle ways.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess what I meant is "resetting". Basically I want to set it back to the same state as an object that is initialized with `= {};`.

Comment: Another issue is padding. Zero-initialization will zero the padding, but assignment is not required to copy it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you are looking for is in [expr.ass]

> A *braced-init-list* may appear on the right-hand side of

> - an assignment to a scalar, in which case the initializer list shall have at most a single element. The
>   meaning of `x={v}`, where T is the scalar type of the expression x, is that of `x=T{v}`. The meaning of
>   `x={}` is `x=T{}`.
> - an assignment to an object of class type, in which case the initializer list is passed as the argument to
>   the assignment operator function selected by overload resolution (13.5.3, 13.3).

So your guess is correct.  The compiler may (can in C++17 and above) be able to optimize things away but you can think of it as create a zero-initialized temporary and pass it to the `operator=`.

Answer (score 16):

`s = {};` is not safe.

The problem is that you *hope* it turns into `s = SomeStruct{};` . However, if `s` has another overload for `operator=` [then that may be preferred by overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511641/overload-resolution-assignment-of-empty-braces).

So this is an anti-pattern, really.   As suggested on the other thread, you're better off writing a function, e.g.:

```
template<typename T> void reset(T &t) { t = T{}; }
```

I guess you could also write `s = decltype(s){};`, so long as `s` was not a reference.

Comment: Why not use your `hoped` for resolution explicitly. `s = SomeStruct{}`? That seems clearer than a function call to `reset()`.

Comment: @LokiAstari well, we might be far from the declaration of `s` so it's not so easy to check that this actually does the right thing.  If we accidentally put `s = SomeOtherStruct{};` then other odd effects could happen.  I try to use code patterns that minimise the possibility for mistakes (particularly, non-obvious mistakes). I guess the `decltype` version is best really. I find that unaesthetic but perhaps I need to update my aesthetics

Comment: I take your point about `SomeOtherStruct{}`. Then it does more sense for the `decltype` but that still looks ugly (and aesthetics are important).